# vb.net INNER Join 3 tables: Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'

Tags: sql, vb.net, inner-join

What's the problem with syntax. I tried to do `INNER JOIN` 3 tables, but I am getting below error message

> **Additional information: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'on'.**

```
SELECT train.id,
       train.class_id,
       train.type_id,
       train.m_year,
       train_type.type,
       train_type.avarage_speed,
       train_class.class,
       train_class.capacity
FROM   train
       INNER JOIN 
            ON  train.class_id = train_class.id
            AND train.type_id = train_type.id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have syntax error in your [join.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp) 
The syntax for join is as follows:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Hence your query will be like the following:

```
 " SELECT train.id, train.class_id, train.type_id, train.m_year, train_type.type," & _
 " train_type.avarage_speed, train_class.class, train_class.capacity FROM train" & _
 " INNER JOIN train_class on train.class_id = train_class.id " & _
 " INNER JOIN train_type on train.type_id = train_type.id"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the 2nd and 3rd tables while using INNER JOIN.

```
INNER JOIN <Table 2> on train.class_id = train_class.id
INNER JOIN <Table 3> on train.type_id = train_type.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your using the three tables for JOIN but not mentioned JOIN correctly

JOIN Syntax

```
(table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID) INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.ID = table3.ID
```

and your query should be like this

```
SELECT train.id,
   train.class_id,
   train.type_id,
   train.m_year,
   train_type.type,
   train_type.avarage_speed,
   train_class.class,
   train_class.capacity
FROM (train
   INNER JOIN train_class
   ON train.class_id = train_class.id)
   INNER JOIN train_type ON train.type_id = train_type.id
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a missed syntax, the table name, your code must be like :

```
SELECT train.id,
    train.class_id,
    train.type_id,
    train.m_year,
    train_type.type,
    train_type.avarage_speed,
    train_class.class,
    train_class.capacity
FROM train
    INNER JOIN train_class
ON  train.class_id = train_class.id
    AND train.type_id = train_type.id
```